# Using pandas pd.cut to generate a categorical variable with statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, categorical-data

I have tried to use pd.cut to create a categorical variable from a continuous variable.  I'd like to use this in a subsequent statsmodel defined regression including this dummy variable.  When I create a categorical variable created in this way, I get an error

```
TypeError: data type not understood.
```

A test case is included below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4))
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df['ttt']=pd.cut(df['D'], bins=2)
test = smf.ols('A ~ B + ttt', data=df).fit()
```

I'm sure I've done something obviously wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your pandas version? If you're on 0.15, then it has new and improved categorical dtypes that were only introduced fairly recently, and other libraries like statsmodels that depend on pandas probably haven't caught up yet.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I'm using pandas 0.15.1. Looks like pandas' new categorical data types are not supported by patsy / statsmodels yet. See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#categorical-is-not-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Yes, I'm also using pandas 0.15.1 and statsmodels 0.6.  This solution worked for me.  Thank you very much for your help.  I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly where statsmodels is at in terms of including support for the new `Categorical` type in pandas. For the moment, you may have to convert the categorical back into an object type for it to work (please check that the resulting ols fit is sensible, I don't know the full details of what you're trying to do):

```
df['ttt_fixed'] = df.ttt.astype(np.object)
test = smf.ols('A ~ B + ttt_fixed', data=df).fit()
test.summary()
```